# Rego: merge arrays from different objects

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

In OPA, I take an input of type `{ roles, action, object }`, and I return a matching permission which contains data regarding what the user is allowed to do based on the input

This is rather simple if no two roles have the same permission:

```
package policies

import data.role_permissions

matching_permission := permission {
  role := input.roles[_]
  permissions := role_permissions[role]
  permission := permissions[_]

  permission.action == input.action
  permission.object == input.object
}
```

The problem arises if the input `roles` has multiple roles that match the same permission, in that case I get an error: `complete rules must not produce multiple outputs`. Which makes sense, so I modified the policy to match an array of permissions:

```
matching_perms[permission] {
  role := input.roles[_]
  permissions := role_permissions[role]
  permission := permissions[_]

  permission.action == input.action
  permission.object == input.object
}
```

But I still need to return a *singe* permission object. What I want to do is merge any extra keys into a single item, with my own logic for each merge conflict
However, I cannot seem to merge the arrays of extra keys in this case.
How would I, for instance, get the following output with this data?:

```json
// data.json
{
  "role_permissions": {
    "a": [{ "action": "read", "object": "threats", "levels": [1, 2, 3] }],
    "b": [{ "action": "read", "object": "threats", "levels": [4, 5] }]
  }
}

// input
{
  "roles": ["a", "b"],
  "action": "read",
  "object": "threats"
}

// desired output
{
  "action": "read",
  "object": "threats",
  "levels": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // <-- Merged into one result
}
```

Basically, how can I merge the permission objects' array fields to create a single object?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - This is the solution I arrived at:

```
package policies

import data.role_permissions

extra_keys(permission) := [key |
    some key
    extra = object.remove(permission, ["action", "object"])
    _ = extra[key]
]

matching_perms[permission] {
    role := input.roles[_]
    permissions := role_permissions[role]
    permission := permissions[_]

    permission.action == input.action
    permission.object == input.object
}

merged_data[key] := result {
    perm := matching_perms[_]
    keys := extra_keys(perm)
    key := keys[_]

    result := {v |
        perm := matching_perms[_]
        permission_data = perm[key]
        v = permission_data[_]
    }
}

permission := {
    "action": input.action,
    "object": input.object,
    "data": merged_data,
}
```

And, if I absolutely need `levels` to sit alongside `action` and `object` rather than nested inside `data`, I use:

```
permission := object.union(
    {
        "action": input.action,
        "object": input.object,
    },
    merged_data,
)
```

The solution was to use a set comprehension for each extra key in my permission object. Using `merged_data[key] := ...` I define an array of data, where I iterate over all extra keys (`key := keys[_]`), then use a set comprehension on `result := {v |` to combine all values in the matching permissions, removing duplicates

Comment: Nice! Yeah, custom merge logic can certainly be a challenge given immutable vars.. but you found a good way.